# Compare all items from a Collection with items from another Collection?

Tags: c#, collections, list

Hey, I have this code here:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
arrayList.add("one");
arrayList.add("two");
arrayList.add("three");

List<DataRow> dataList = GetDataList(some params);
```

Now I want to check if arrayList contains ther elements from dataList. The string is at itemarray[0] in dataList. Is there a nice short code version to do that?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .NET 3.5 to check if all the elements from one list are contained in another list:

```
bool result = list.All(x => dataList.Contains(x));
```

Or you can do it using a combination of [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) and [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
bool result = !list.Except(dataList).Any();
```

In your example you are using an `ArrayList`. You should change this to `List<object>` or `List<string>` to use these methods. Otherwise you can write `arrayList.Cast<object>()`.

```
bool result = arrayList.Cast<object>().All(x => dataList.Contains(x));
```

Comment: Thanks, are you sure about the first one? I only have All for the dataList?

Comment: I would strongly advise you not to use ArrayList in new code. Use List<T> instead. See my update.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I changed it to be List<string>, but still, one list has <DataRow>, the other string. Something is still missing...

Comment: I made it work by calling All on the dataList and using ItemArray.
Thanks!